# Extracting items inside a string

Tags: java, string, indexing, substring

I want to extract Hello world inside a particular string currently i am getting first and last Occurences.there are 3(three) hello world text inside a string i want them on each particular string.

```
String text="hellogfddfdfsdsworldhelloasaasasdasdggworldfdfdsdhellodasasddworld";
int x=text.indexOf("hello");
int y=text.indexOf("world");
String test=text.substring(x, y+4);
System.out.println(test);
x=text.indexOf("hello");
y=text.indexOf("world");
String test1=text.substring(x,y);
System.out.println(test1);
x=text.lastIndexOf("hello");
y=text.lastIndexOf("world);
String test2=text.substring(x, y);
System.out.println(test2);
```

Comment: Not really an expert, but I think `regex` can serve your needs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a regular expression. The simplest one would be

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "hello # Match 'hello'\n" +
    ".*?   # Match 0 or more characters (any characters), as few as possible\n" +
    "world # Match 'world'", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

If you only want the text *between* `hello` and `world`, use

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "hello # Match 'hello'\n" +
    "(.*?) # Match 0 or more characters (any characters), as few as possible\n" +
    "world # Match 'world'", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Note that this fails if patterns can be nested, i. e. `hello foo hello bar world baz world`.